# Changing Compare Two Images Row to Responsive Grid

Tags: grid, row

I see the Compare Two Images from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_image_compare. And, I have made it to displayed it on multiple rows and columns but the images are overlapping when showing on a smaller screen. How do I make it a responsive grid?